# StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() escaping unknown characters. How to remove that?

Tags: java, xml

I am getting following string `B.A&#55356;&#57232; registered` after escaping using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(message)`. Here `&#55356;` and `&#57232;` are unknown unicode characters. I want to remove them after escape. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: What string are you escaping in the first case?

Comment: That is unknown to me as I am getting escaped string and I have to post it to atom feed server where it is failing because of unknown character.

Comment: My guess is that there is an encoding problem somewhere, possibly when you retrieve the data, possibly in an earlier stage. You are better off fixing the source of the problem as it will be difficult to create a list of invalid characters.

Comment: sound reasonable. thnx

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to remove illegal characters before escaping. Have a look at https://github.com/jillesvangurp/xmltools/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jillesvangurp/xmltools/ValidXMLCharacterFilterReader.java

This is a class I implemented years ago to filter out illegal characters in XML content. Possible causes of illegal characters could be character encoding issues.